# using symmetry of axis / point in pgfplot?

Tags: pgfplots

Is there a way to use symmetry of axis or a point in `pgfplot`?

So that you have only to define half numbers of the coordinates or only one quarter?

e.g. for doing things like this:
[image]

with less effort?

example code with data (table) for "one quarter" which should be "mirrored" to achieve something like the figure above:

```
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

%%%% for speed only: %%%%%%
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzsetexternalprefix{tikz-fig-precomp-cache/}
%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
ymin=0,
ymax=0.7]
\addplot  [smooth, color=blue]
table{
90 0.4
30 0.45
0 0.47
};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Polar}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Are you plotting functions, or data from a file?

Comment: we have data no function

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a minimal example document with some (dummy) data to make it clearer how your input is organised?

Comment: just added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for polar plots. In TikZ(and hence in pgfplots) one can reuse the same poth for different purposes via post and preactions. Then it is a matter of timing to catch and squeeze in extra transformation somewhere.

I've defined(mostly by stealing from the original) a simple use style that requires some path drawing specs and x scale and a y scale via

```
mirrored postaction=<path action> via <xscale> and <yscale>
```

Please, take this as a starting point an modify further for your needs.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@extra@mirr@red@postaction#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \pgfsys@beginscope%
      \pgflowlevel{%
      \pgftransformxscale{#2}%
      \pgftransformyscale{#3}}%
      \setbox\tikz@figbox=\box\pgfutil@voidb@x%
      \tikz@restorepathsize%
      \path[#1]\pgfextra{\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath\tikz@actions@path};
      \pgf@resetpathsizes%
    \pgfsys@endscope%
  }%
}

\tikzset{mirrored postaction/.code args={#1 via #2 and #3}{%
\expandafter\def\expandafter\tikz@postactions\expandafter{%
    \tikz@postactions\tikz@extra@mirr@red@postaction{#1}{#2}{#3}
    }
  }
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[
xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,
ymin=0,
ymax=0.7]
\addplot [smooth, color=blue,
mirrored postaction=draw via 1 and -1,
mirrored postaction={ultra thick,dashed,draw} via -1 and 1,
mirrored postaction={ultra thin,red,fill} via -1 and -1,]
table{
90 0.4
80 0.7
70 0.6
60 0.8
50 1.5
30 0.45
10 -0.1
0 0.47
};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Here I've used the same path three times with different drawing specs and a red fill. As seen from this example, you can invoke post and preactions more than once.

[image]

In your example the result becomes

[image]

You can even embed those three mirrored postaction styles into one style and make it even more convenient.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advise! Works great. It only took a small moment until I realized that it do not work together with

     \usepgfplotslibrary{external}
     \tikzexternalize

Comment: @hpvd Strange. It should work though. Can you update your MWE with the extarnlization details?

Comment: thanks for your question. Just added these lines in my example.

Comment: @hpvd I have no problem with the externalization. Can you check whether you have the updated packages and you are not using custom settings?

Comment: many thanks for your effort.

hmm -I have the latest package installed.

Maybe you could please give me the full code you have tested e.g. by updating the code above?

Comment: which kind of compiling syntax do you use? I use pdflatex plus switch "-enable-write18" with miktex. This works with all other code perfect...

Comment: @hpvd Same here actually. Ah, maybe it's the CVS version of TikZ that makes the difference, I have the beta version of the new release installed.

Comment: ah ok then I will just wait for the next release of TikZ and test it again.

Comment: installed a newer (beta) version of TiKZ but it doesn't do the trick...

Comment: tried this version  TikZ/PGF 2.10 CVS (build 2013-04-12) from http://perso.mines-albi.fr/~gaborit/latex/tikz-pgf.html

Comment: @hpvd I can't think of why it is breaking down. The last thing I can think of is that you can't create a directory in the working directory. Can you paste the error you get?

Comment: ok I cleaned everything from external, all aux...- and now it works great! Seems to be the man in front of the computer... Many thanks for your patience!

Comment: @hpvd Hahah, my pleasure.